# how to create a gradle and spring project in intellij (ultimate)

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

In intellij, you can either create a gradle project, or a spring projected, but not both.

Assuming one creates a spring project, how does one then add gradle using the IDE?

When you create a spring project in intellij, you can also add groovy which is nice. Having groovy support as part of the gradle build for spring would be a big bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select "Spring Initializr" in "New Project" dialog. It will create spring project with maven/gradle support.

Comment: I didnt know what what spring initializer was, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

IMO the easiest way is to generate target gradle config using https://start.spring.io, then just open is as project from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a spring project and if you add a `build.gradle` file afterwards Intellij will ask you if you want to import it as a Gradle project.

This can be also done manually through [gradle tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#link_gradle_project).